# How to use Spring Rest Service with REST Component in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule Studio and I want to use Spring Rest Service with REST component in the Mule. So how can I access Spring REST features with REST Component I don't want to use Jersey way of creating REST service with Mule.

I just want to declare one REST controller with spring annotation that will automatically invoke.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mules Rest Component is a Jersey implementation of JAX-RS which loads the resource classes so that they can be accesses as Rest URLs.

Spring Rest Controller is the Spring way of creating a Rest service which runs ona web-container. 
If you want to run the SpringRestController based rest service on Mule you can package and deploy it directly on Mule standalone. Mule can run a web applicaiton as it contains an embedded Jetty container.

Unfortunately you cannot include a Spring RestController into the Mules's REST component(which is a Jersey implementation).  Controller's purpose is not to serve as a component.

By the way in Mule also you just need to specify the annotations and provide the resource class to the REST component. Mule takes care of the rest.

Hope this helps.